Is it possible to set a transparent background for textInput with pdf-lib?
I would like to create an editing interface where the textInputs are filled in on the server side. It would be necessary to set the background of the fields to transparent, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.
Thank you in advance for any answers.
Thank you in advance for any answers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Certainly it is possible to set transparency for PDF-lib.js text fields. Here the transparency is set in the sample PDF output. It has been in the lib for some long time, though raised several times in questions and answers.
The documentation is not providing clear example but it is an optional field appearances variable. See https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/fieldappearanceoptions#properties
superheroField.setText('One Punch Man', { backgroundColor: undefined})

However it is usually pointless for 2 reasons one is most viewers with page transparency need to fill the fields blue to distinguish them, and those that do not, will fill them with the white background.



Thanks for the quick answer, but unfortunately I don't see a second parameter option for setText. It doesn't cause an error if I write it there, but it doesn't affect the final result and the documentation doesn't show such a parameter either.
https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdftextfield#settext
